# Rhino Mocks - Verify Property Set when Property has no Get

Tags: properties, rhino-mocks, setter

If you have a property:

```
public class Fred
{
   public string UserName
   {
     set
     {
        userName=value;
     }
   }
}
```

how do you use Rhino Mocks to check that

```
fred= new Fred();
fred.UserName="Jim";
```

is called.

```
Expect.Call(mockFred.UserName).SetPropertyWithArgument("Jim");
```

does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to do a verify all on the property set

```
[TestClass]
public class FredTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFred()
    {
        var mocker = new MockRepository();
        var fredMock = mocker.DynamicMock<IFred>();

        fredMock.UserName = "Name";
        // the last call is actually to the set method of username
        LastCall.IgnoreArguments(); 
        mocker.ReplayAll();

        fredMock.UserName = "Some Test that does this.";
        mocker.VerifyAll();
    }

}

public interface IFred
{
    string UserName { set; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is using MsTests so you may have to adjust your attributes accordingly

Comment: Thank you - for reasons that are totally beyond me, when I tried what you suggested it didn't work. It does now. Silly me - thank you.

Comment: So do I get the approved answer?

Comment: Of course you do - my first question - still learning about site - will be much quicker next time!

Answer (score 27):

```
public interface IFred
{
    string UserName { set; }
}

[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    IFred fred = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFred>();
    fred.UserName = "Jim";
    fred.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UserName = "Jim");
}
```